How is the prefix function (for KMP) time complexity O(N)?
I'm looking at the algorithm for the prefix function from here https://cp-algorithms.com/string/prefix-function.html :
vector<int> prefix_function(string s) {
    int n = (int)s.length();
    vector<int> pi(n);
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        int j = pi[i-1];
        while (j > 0 && s[i] != s[j])
            j = pi[j-1];
        if (s[i] == s[j])
            j++;
        pi[i] = j;
    }
    return pi;
}

In the worst case the variable "j" within the while loop halves in value. Hence the time complexity should be O(n*log(n)) and not O(n)? What's wrong with my reasoning?

The idea is to apply amortized analysis instead of summing up the worst cases. Any good textbook should contain a detailed analysis of this.

You are also wrong about the "halving". j can decrease by only 1 as well, take for example the string aaaaaaab

@EnEm oh right, i incorrectly thought that pi[j] is at most j/2

I figured it out. j never goes negative and it increases by at most n times. Thus the while loop (which always decreases j) will run a lifetime total of not more than n times.
